# Write dictionary output of each run in a loop to newline in a file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a for loop which will generate a dictionary for each run. How can I write each dictionary to a new line in the file? Present code is overwriting the data present in file
Present code:

```
for i in ():
  ...
  ...
  with open("/Users/myfile.txt", 'a') as f:
       (json.dumps(modified_hosts),f)
```

Sample dictionary

```
{'date': '2023-12-07', 'hostname': 'abc', 'present_value': 3, 'updated_value': 49}
```

How can I save all these values in tabular form in a file?

Comment: That doesn't write anything to the file.  Did you mean `json.dump(modified_hosts, f)`?

Comment: And, by the way, appending JSON like that makes the file NOT valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, updated the code.  Correct that not making a valid JSON file.
Not sure what will be the fix

Comment: Can you please what `modified_hosts` looks like?

Comment: If you want it to be tabular, then why not write it tabular?  Or even a CSV?